# How to make binary tree from edges?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am getting all the edges of the binary tree from the input in the from

```
   parentId childId
   e.g. 0 3 // means from node 0 to node 3
   // 0 does not mean root of the tree.
```

How do i construct the tree from this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to do this in two passes:

1. Assemble all of the links in the tree.
2. Find the root of the tree.

To assemble all the links, you could start off by building a hash table keyed by the ID of each node (or a giant array of the appropriate size if you know that the IDs are all in the range 0 ... N for some choice of N).  Whenever you read a line from the file, you can do the following:

1. If nodes don't already exist with IDs specified by the start and end point, create those nodes and initially set their left and right pointers to NULL.
2. Add the second node as a child of the first.  (I'm assuming that this is not a binary search tree, so the order of the children doesn't matter.  If this is a binary search tree, then you can set the appropriate child pointer based on what you find).

To find the root of the tree, you can make a set of nodes that are candidates for the root node, which initially is every node in the tree.  You can then iterate across the nodes you have constructed so far.  Every time that you find that a node v is a child of another node u, you can remove node v from the set of candidate roots (since it's a child).  When you're done, you will be left with the set of all possible roots.  If the list of edges really does define a binary tree, this will be just one node.  If it defines a forest of binary trees, this gives you back the roots of all the trees in the forest.

Overall, this takes O(n) time, where n is the number of edges (also the number of nodes in the tree, since the number of edges in a binary tree is the number of nodes minus one).

You could roll these two passes into one pass if you wanted to; I've just described them separately for ease of presentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not helpful. Please share code

Answer (score 0):

first you build a map of node id, to list of connected nodes
then iterage through the map and create the from, to links from your info in the map

if it is a binary tree, then there is missing info in the file, there should be in format

parent, leftChild, rightChild or 
or left and right are always in same order ( left first) and two rows per node, the second on the next line.

Comment: The file is fine as is, it doesn't have to be in the form you suggested. There'll just be up to 2 rows per node (as a parent), one for each child.

Comment: yes, but then left subtree should ever be first,